# Gmail filter for specific day of the week

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Is there a filter in Gmail that will sort your emails by date?

For example if you get filters from address "X" on a certain day of the week, can you create a folder for just that mail (with an autoresponder if possible).

Comment: Just so that I understand, do you want to create a filter like "if received on Saturday or Sunday, apply label weekend and auto respond"?

Comment: There is nothing in native Gmail that will change the sorting. Do you mean a filter?

Answer (score 1):

Just put: before:2011/01/01 and you'll get old emails. Better this than nothing...

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can always make a filter with characteristics of the e-mails.

Answer (score 0):

You are now able to query for relative dates using `d`, `m`, and `y` for day, month, and year.

For example: use `newer_than:2d` to find messages sent within the last two days.

Otherwise, you can install this Chrome extension: [Date filters for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/date-filters-for-gmail/ingccfmdangdapfhfmnhicpmfbofhhlo?hl=en)